# Is it possible to prove that $|\sup (f+g)| \le |\sup f| + |\sup g|$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let C the space of continuous functions $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb R$. How to prove that  $|\sup (f+g)| \le |\sup f| + |\sup g|$?
I thought that it was a simple consequence of the well-known fact that  $\sup (f+g) \le \sup f + \sup g$. But I don't know if the inequality holds when we apply the modulus function on both sides.

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: @leslietownes the sup of the absolute values does not necessarily equal the absolute value of the sup.

Comment: I don't see the consequence of the triangle inequality. The value of the $\sup (f+g)$ can be negative.

Comment: just a quick observation for people just glancing at this quickly, note that OP has NOT asked to prove $\sup (|f+g|) \le \sup| f| + \sup |g|$ (which is true), they have asked to prove $|\sup (f+g)| \le |\sup f| + |\sup g|$. Which I believe Arturo Magidin has just contradicted :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inequality need not hold.

Take $f(x)=-x-1$ and $g(x)=x-2$, so $(f+g)(x) = -3$. Then $|\sup(f+g)|=|-3|=3$. On the other hand, $f$ is decreasing, so $\sup f=f(0)=-1$, and $g$ is increasing, so $\sup(g)=g(1)=-1$, so $|\sup f|+|\sup g|=|-1|+|-1|=2$.

Thus, $|\sup(f+g)|\gt |\sup f|+|\sup g|$ in this instance.

Though of course it is *possible* it holds, per your subject line. It will hold in many cases, e.g., when the functions are nonnegative, or when $\sup(f+g)\geq 0$, among others.

---

In the comments you ask about the inequality
$$|\sup(f+g)|+|\inf(f+g)|\leq |\sup f|+|\sup g| + |\inf f| + |\inf g|.$$
This inequality also need not hold; it's a bit easier to find counterexamples, because all we need is a pair of nonnegative functions with $\sup(f+g)=\sup(f)+\sup(g)$ and $\inf(f+g)\gt \inf(f)+\inf(g)$, and those are plentiful

One example is to take
$$f(x) =\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1&\text{if }1\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}\\
2-2x&\text{if }\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq 1
\end{array}\right.\qquad\text{and}\qquad
g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
1-2x&\text{if }0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2}\\
2x-1 &\text{if }\frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq 1.
\end{array}\right.$$
It is easy to verify that $\sup(f)=\sup(g)=1$, $\inf(f)=\inf(g)=0$.
Now,
$$(f+g)(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2 - 2x&\text{if }0\leq x\leq\frac{1}{2}\\
1&\text{if }\frac{1}{2}\leq x \leq 1.
\end{array}\right.$$
So $\sup(f+g) = 2$ (achieved at $x=0$), and $\inf(f+g)=1$. So we have
$$\sup(f+g) + \inf(f+g) = 2+1 = 3 \gt 2 = \sup(f)+\inf(f)+\sup(g)+\inf(g).$$

Comment: I knew that some contraexample exists but maybe the inequality that I really want to show is true:
$|\sup(f+g)| + |\inf(f+g)| \le |\sup f| + |\sup g| + |\inf g| + |\inf f|$.

In your contraexample, this inequality holds.

Comment: @ÁtilaLuna It is hard to answer questions you *maybe* want to ask, but not **actually** ask.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality fails already in two dimensional space, or equivalently functions on the two point set $\{0,1\}.$ Consider $(0,-1)$ and $(-1,0).$ Then the left hand side of the inequality is equal $1$ while the right hand side is equal $0.$ This immediately can be extended to $C[0,1]$ by taking strictly monotonic functions $f$ and $g$ such that $(f(0),f(1)) =(0,-1)$ and $(g(0),g(1))=(-1,0).$ Then $f+g$ is negative, so RHS is positive while LHS is equal $0.$ For example $f(x)=-x,$ $g(x)=x-1.$